# table Contacts has no column named userId (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):

Tags: android, sqlite

My App is not able to save the data into the SQLite database and throwing the above error and then the app crash. My helper class is

public class SQLiteOpenHelper extends android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DirectDB";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Contacts";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
private static final String KEY_NUMBER = "Number";
private static final String KEY_IS_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS = "IsUserAlreadyExists";
private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "userId";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE_URL = "ProfileImageUrl";


public SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Contacts ( " + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT,Number TEXT,ProfileImageUrl TEXT,IsUserAlreadyExists TEXT,userId TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATION_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertContact(PhoneContactModel phoneContactModel) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, phoneContactModel.getDisplayName());
    values.put(KEY_NUMBER, phoneContactModel.getPhoneNumber());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE_URL, phoneContactModel.getContactImageUrl());
    values.put(KEY_IS_USER_ALREADY_EXISTS, phoneContactModel.getIsUserAlreadyExists());
    values.put(KEY_USER_ID, phoneContactModel.getUserId());
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

}

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change your code this error thrown when you add a new node to your table and try to add data to them without re-installing your app. Simply re-install your app and you do not face this error.

Comment: This solves my problem. Thank you @Akshay